# Assembler (TASM x64) arrays and elements

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, dos, tasm

I have an array of nine names:

```
.model  tiny

.data 

vardas1 db "Rokas",0ah,'$'
vardas2 db "Tomas",0ah,'$'
vardas3 db "Matas",0ah,'$'
vardas4 db "Domas",0ah,'$'
vardas5 db "Augis",0ah,'$'
vardas6 db "Vofka",0ah,'$'
vardas7 db "Marka",0ah,'$'
vardas8 db "Auris",0ah,'$'
vardas9 db "Edvis",0ah,'$'


vardai dw offset vardas1, offset vardas2, offset vardas3, offset vardas4, offset vardas5, offset vardas6, offset vardas7, offset vardas8, offset vardas9

.code

org 100h
```

I need to read a digit from keyboard, and then I need to print that name. For example I will push 5, and console should write "Augis". BTW, second code block aren't all code, just loop that doesn't work

```
paieska:

    mov dx, offset _comment1        ; Just string name asking user to input digit 
    mov ah, 9                       
    int 21h                         

    mov j, 00h                      ; Trying to input the digit from keyboard 
    mov ah, 01h
    mov dl, 0ah
    int 21h

    mov bx, offset vardai           ; Add array "names" to bx register
    add bx, cx                      ; Add cx for indexing
    mov dx, [bx]                    ; Add first array element to dx register

    add cx, 2                       ; Increasing cx by 2, because I'm using data word not data byte
    mov ah, 9                       ; Try to print it
    int 21h


    cmp cx, j                       ; Try to compare cx (index of array) to mine inputed digit "j"
    jne paieska
    je end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I find a little unclear this question which is the problem and which is your question? And please, show just the code that it is relevant for us.

Comment: What is the question? You should clarify what is not working (error message, application crash, ...) and where you need help as it is not obvious for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
  mov ah, 01h
  mov dl, 0ah ;NO NEED FOR THIS - INT21/01 DOES NOT USE DL
  int 21h

  MOV AH, '1'     ; MIN INPUT CHAR
  mov bx, offset vardai ; Add array "names" to bx register WELL, ASSIGN ACTUALLY
  MOV CX,2        ;NUMBER OF BYTES TO ADD (WORDS, NOT BYTES)
LOOPN:
  mov dx, [bx]    ; name-pointer array element to dx register
  CMP AH,AL       ; MATCHING char?
  JE  PNAME       ; YES, PRINT NAME
  add bx, cx      ; Add cx=2 for next name
  inc AH          ; next possible character input
  CMP AH,'9'+1    ; allowed is '1'..'9'
  jne loopn       ; in allowed range
; input not 1..9
  mov dx, offset errormessage
PNAME:
  mov ah, 9       ; Try to print it
  int 21h
  jmp end
```

Well, I tried to edit your approach with CAPS, but it became too complicated.

Essentially, you are reading a character from the keyboard using function `01`. This character arrives in AL. If all goes well, it should be '1'..'9'. Notice these are the ASCII characters '1'..'9', that is hex 31..39

Next step is to set `BX` to the start of the table, `AH` to the minimum character you anticipate and `CX` to 2 because the table contains words, not bytes.

Now we have a loop. Load `X` from the table, and check whether `AL` is equal to `AH`. If the user input `1`, these will be equal, so go print the string.

Otherwise, add 2 to `BX` to point to the next entry in the table (this could have been done by `ADD BX,2` or `INC BX INC BX` which would mean the `MOV CX,2` would be unnecessary - just the way I wrote it...) and increment the `'1'` in `AH` to `'2'`.

The end-condition for the loop is when `AH` gets incremented from `'9'` to - well, `':'` or `'9'+1`. If it hasn't reached that end-condition, then run around the loop until all of the values `'1'`..`'9'` have been tested. If you haven't got to `PNAME` yet, then there's an error because the character input wasn't allowed, so point to an error message and then print it.

Now jumping to the end - probably you'd want to terminate the program, so you'd execute

```
  MOV AH,4CH
  INT 21H
```